# BlackJack deck, shuffling the cards

Tags: vb.net

For some reason in this code, my s.Remove() isn't working. Can anybody tell me why and help me come up with a solution??

```
Private Sub ShuffleDeck()
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim s As String = "23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA23456789bJQKA"
    For i As Integer = 1 To prng.Next(208, 208)
        Dim rndCard As String = prng.Next(0, s.Length)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(rndCard), 1)
        s.Remove(rndCard, 1)
    Next
    deck = sb.ToString()
    Clipboard.SetText(deck)
End Sub
```

I have it there so my deck doesn't have 20 2s and 15 3s and so on... There's supposed to be 16 of each number and face card since this is a game with 4 decks.

Comment: There are multiple issues there, but when you examine the intellisense for `Strign.Remove` note that it is a function returning the modified string.  Strings are immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating from `1 To prng.Next(208, 208)` does not make any sense. The latter will always return 208, so no need to put a `Random` there.

As to why it's not working: `s.Remove(rndCard, 1)` returns a new String instance from which the chosen character has been removed. You need to reassign that new String to your `s`.

But as you can guess, this is not optimal in terms of performance because you are creating new String objects during each iteration. A better way might be to make your `s` into a `StringBuilder` as well, so you can remove things in place without creating new instances.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I can't believe I didn't think of that before. Assigning s to s.Remove(rndCard, 1) did the trick, of course. As far as the "1 to prng.next(208, 208)", I had set to "1 to prng.Next(0, 208)" but of course that didn't work, so I changed it to what I have now so I could check if it worked and I haven't changed it yet.